# How to edit the "new-menu" on the main page

Tags: sitepages, menu, homepage

I have created a team website and just want to give the users the possibility to create new sitepages on the start page. But if you click on the menu [image: drop-down-menu] many options shows up. You can see a lot, but I don't want my users to see that. There should only be the entry "Page"!

[image: homepage]

How can I edit this menu? I have not yet been able to discover any options. I am the owner of this website, so I should have all necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling permission is the only way to manipulate what the user sees in the "New" dropdown. There is no option to customize it, but the user will only see the options they have permission to do.

If you make sure your users only have the "Contribute" level permission, and not "Edit", then they can create Items, Documents, and Pages, but will not have options to create lists, libraries, and apps.  I know that "Edit" and "Contribute" sound like similar permissions, but "Edit" means Editing site and list structure, whereas "Contribute" means being able to add and manipulate the contents in those lists and libraries.

Comment: With the permission settings I can't change this drop-down, because the users should be able to create new "Modern pages", but nothing else... Do you have any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: If you make sure they do **not** have "Edit" Permission -- I know the name of the permission sounds like what you want, but in SharePoint, "Edit" permissions explicitly give the user the rights to "Add, edit, and delete **lists**".  The "Contribute" permission on the other hand only grants the rights to "View, add, update, and delete **list items and documents**."  If the users only have "Contibute" they will, for example, be able to create and edit pages, but not change the structure of the Site Page Library, or to update or edit a document, but not create a new document library.

Comment: When i open the "new drop-down menu", a user will see the following entries: list, document library, page, news post, news link, plan, app. Okay, then I take the permission level to "Manage lists - create or delete lists, create or delete columns of a list, and add or delete public views of a list.  " out of the permission level. Now the list and document library should disappear from the menu. Then what about the entries: News Item, News Link, Plan and App? How do I get rid of them?

Comment: News items and news links are types of pages, however, App should not be visible to contributors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Admin rights, You should see Edit New Menu at the bottom.
Select it and it opens a bar on the right hand side.
Here you can select which options you want to make available by unchecking them and saving.
You can also add or remove the option to add a new folder entirely by going to advanced settings.
Make sure you are in the library you wish to edit, click on the settings Cog, select library settings. Select Advanced settings, look for Make "New Folder" command available? half way down.
You can also restrict sync & search functions here.